# Change Excel cell color from C# script

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, npoi

I have some cells cached in the C# script that I want to change their font color from code to diferentiate their values, there is any way in C# to do this?

I am already using the libraries NPOI and DocumentFormat.OpenXml, but I do not find how to change the font color with them.

I want something similar to this, change the value from black to red:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a "google" search? I found this one on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267550/npoi-does-not-change-cell%c2%b4s-font-color

Answer (score 0):

```
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
Font font = wb.createFont();
font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
style.setFont(font);
```

for the cached cell use above code to change the color.

Comment: I have a similar code and it does nothing 

IFont font = xssWorkbook.CreateFont();
font.Color = XSSFFont.DEFAULT_FONT_COLOR;
ICellStyle defaultStyle = xssWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();
defaultStyle.SetFont(font);


And below, when setting the cell color:
cell.CellStyle = defaultStyle;

Comment: For more context, I am using this excel only to read the info inside, the font color is the only thing I want to "write" in the excel.